# Color Mapping For Specific Range

Tags: java, colors, color-scheme

I have a small problem, I'm trying to draw different color points, the color must depend on a certain value associated with the point within a maximum range and a minimum range. And I would like the color scaling to be made between red - yellow - green.

Now, I've associated with red, the maximum value, while the green color is associated with the minimum value. For all other intermediate points, I would like to go from green to yellow to red, the problem I do not know how to set everything to get yellow, because now I can only pass through green and red gradations.

code:

```
red = (int) (value * (255));
green = 255 - red;
blue = 0 ;

Color color = new Color((int) red, (int) green, (int) blue);
String hex = Integer.toHexString(color.getRGB() & 0xffffff);
```

The range goes from 1 (MAX) to 0 (MIN), so the value is inside this range [0,1].

How can I fix everything to get also yellow gradients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the HSV color space. By varying the Hue component, you can make the color shift in the way you want.

```
float value = 0; //this is your value between 0 and 1
float minHue = 120f/255; //corresponds to green
float maxHue = 0; //corresponds to red
float hue = value*maxHue + (1-value)*minHue; 
Color c = new Color(Color.HSBtoRGB(hue, 1, 0.5f));
```

This interpolates the hue of the min and max colors. If you want to interpolate between colors that don't have the same value and saturation. Interpolate between these as well.

Comment: I actually have points for which each of them is associated with a value that is between 0 and 1. When a point has value 1 then I have to redeem it, if it has 0 I have to color it green, in all other cases i have to do One scaling between them, and for example if the value is 0.5 I have to color it yellow.

Comment: I hope I have explained it better.

Comment: @traveller see my updated answer, this should work for you.

Answer (score 4):

Use **HSB** model instead of RGB. In HSB you just need to specify angle of desired color. `Color#getHSBColor(float h, float s, float b);`. [Here](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/hsv-to-rgb.htm) you can try to mix HSB (HSV) color.

[image: HSB Model]

Here is an example how to create n distinct colors in specified color-interval:

```
public static Color[] intervalColors(float angleFrom, float angleTo, int n) {
    float angleRange = angleTo - angleFrom;
    float stepAngle = angleRange / n;

    Color[] colors = new Color[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        float angle = angleFrom + i*stepAngle;
        colors[i] = Color.getHSBColor(angle, 1.0, 1.0);        
    }
    return colors;
}
...
    Color[] colors = intervalColors(0, 120, 10); // red to green
    Arrays.sort(colors, Comparator.reversed()); // green to red
```

To map color to value from range <0,1>:

```
/**
 * Remaps x from old-interval to new-interval.
 * DoubleInterval just wraps double values a, b.
 */
public static double remap(double x, DoubleInterval oldDomain, DoubleInterval newDomain) {
    double oldRange = oldDomain.size(); // oldDomain.b - oldDomain.a
    double oldRangeValue = x - oldDomain.a; // lowerBound a is just an offset
    double percentile = oldRangeValue / oldRange;

    double newRange = newDomain.size(); // newDomain.b - newDomain.a
    double newRangeValue = percentile * newRange;
    double newVal = newRangeValue + newDomain.a;
    return newVal;
}

/**
 * Returns color from specified color-interval that matches normValue <0,1>.
 * If normValue = 0, angleFrom = 0 (red), angleTo = 120 (green) then color = red. 
 */
public static Color intervalColor(float normValue, float angleFrom, float angleTo) {
    double angleValue = remap(normValue, new DoubleInterval(0, 1), new DoubleInterval(angleFrom, angleTo));
    return Color.getHSBColor(angleValue, 1.0, 1.0);        
}

/**
 * Returns inversion of specified value in given domain.
 * Example: if x = 0.3 and domain of x is <0,1> then inversion = 0.7
 */
public static double invert(double x, DoubleInterval domain) {
    return (domain.b - x) + domain.a;
}

/**
 * Returns color from specified color-interval that matches inverted normValue <0,1>.
 * If normValue = 0 and angleFrom = 0 (red) and angleTo = 120 (green) then color = green. 
 */
public static Color invertedIntervalColor(float normValue, float angleFrom, float angleTo) {
    double invNormValue = invert(normValue, new DoubleInterval(0, 1));
    return intervalColor(invNormValue, angleFrom, angleTo);      
}
```